# Hard problem of pulleys

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, string

A string passes over a frictionless, massless pulley attached to the ceiling A mass $m_1$ hangs from one end of this string, and a second
massless, frictionless pulley hangs from the other end. A second string passes
over the second pulley, and a mass $m2$ hangs from one end of this string,
whereas the other end is attached firmly to the ground. Draw separate "freebody" diagrams for the mass mu the second pulley, and the mass m2. Find the accelerations of the mass m,, the second pulley, and the mass m2.

[image]